# Richtextbox vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

when my RichTextBox full of words, i did use GetScrollInfo to get nMax, nMin & nPage. but after i clear all text (scroll bar is gone), the nMax, nMin & nPage still remain the previous data. is there any way to make it auto update the GetScrollInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the event `RichTextBox.TextChanged`:

```
private void myRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get whatever you need in here
}
```

Comment: thanks but i already tried this. it just remain to the previous data